# Error Invalid format: [ISO8601] when indexing logs in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I see an exception when I try to index my logs into ElasticSearch (1.3.4). The root cause of the exception I see is the following (edited my initial post to provide the full stacktrace)

```
[2015-01-09 15:53:00,953][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.create] [perfgen04 1] [logaggr-2015.01.09] failed to create
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: mapping [test]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService$2.execute(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:386)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:328)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: [ISO8601]: Illegal pattern component: I
    at org.elasticsearch.common.joda.Joda.forPattern(Joda.java:160)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.joda.Joda.forPattern(Joda.java:37)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.TypeParsers.parseDateTimeFormatter(TypeParsers.java:295)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.DateFieldMapper$TypeParser.parse(DateFieldMapper.java:155)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseProperties(ObjectMapper.java:289)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseObjectOrDocumentTypeProperties(ObjectMapper.java:217)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.RootObjectMapper$TypeParser.parse(RootObjectMapper.java:136)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:209)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parseCompressed(DocumentMapperParser.java:190)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:440)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.merge(MapperService.java:313)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService$2.execute(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:383)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: I
    at org.elasticsearch.common.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.parsePatternTo(DateTimeFormat.java:570)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.createFormatterForPattern(DateTimeFormat.java:693)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DateTimeFormat.java:181)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.joda.Joda.forPattern(Joda.java:158)
    ... 16 more
```

I am using logstash (1.4.2) to send my logs to ElasticSearch. My grok filter is pretty simple and is as follows. I am keeping the timestamp as a string "logts".

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => [ "message", "%{DATA:logts}%{SPACE}\[%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:thread}]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:classname}]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:details}" ]
    }    
}
```

A sample line from my log file is:

```
2015-01-09 14:53:07,035-0800 [ERROR] [pool-1-thread-2] [LogGenerator] invocation count=101,time=95840107816543,metric=6688916707300087716
```

I ran logstash with '-vv' flag and I don't see any "[ISO8601]" in the output.

Does anyone know where the invalid format is being introduced?

The Gist is available [here](https://gist.github.com/curious3/5bb05cb0c58a681e4527).

Comment: The error message that you put in the subject line doesn't appear in what you've pasted.  Your pattern works fine in the debugger.  Note the "Illegal pattern component: I".

Comment: I suspect the OP has another config file in /etc/logstash/conf.d. I'd try `grep ISO8601 /etc/logstash/conf.d/*`.

Comment: Edited my question showing the error message I have in my title. It looks like an attempt to parse a format string "ISO8601" which in turn  complains about the "Illegal pattern component: I". But I cannot explain where it gets the "ISO8601" format from. I checked my /etc/logstash/conf.d and don't have any config files there.

Comment: Update: Added "date_detection" : false as in this doc (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-root-object-type.html) but I still see the Invalid format error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted my Elasticsearch installation (this was a test environment) and reinstalled and this started working again.

I suspect if I had deleted my index it would have solved the problem as well.